# What is the relevant that should be between the timers interval and the progressBar steps?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a method in form1 where i use a progressBar:

```
counter += 1;
int position = (int)Math.Round((counter / updateTime) * 100);
xpProgressBar1.Text = position.ToString() + " %";
xpProgressBar1.Position = position;
if (counter == 10)
{
  counter = 0;
}
```

And the timers in the new class:

```
public static void Start(Form1 form)
        {
            frm1 = form;
            _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
            _timer1.Elapsed += _timer1_Elapsed;
            _timer.Interval = 1000;
            _timer1.Interval = 1000;
            count = 5;
            LoadOldHtmlFiles();
            frm1.CombindedStringFix();
            _timer.Start();
            _timer1.Start();
        }
```

If i set _timer interval to 10000 and leave _timer1 interval on 1000 and the progressbar will move by 10% each time and get to 100% after 10 seconds.

But now i want everything to move faster so i changed _timer interval from 10000 to 1000.
What should i change now in the progressBar code so it will jump each second to 100% ? ( If im not wrong this is the logic if i change the timer interval to 1000 so the progressBar should jump each second to 100% ).

```
counter += 1;
            int position = (int)Math.Round((counter / updateTime) * 100);
            xpProgressBar1.Text = position.ToString() + " %";
            xpProgressBar1.Position = position;
            if (counter == 10)
            {
                counter = 0;
            }
```

What should i change the counter == 10 to ? And should i change also something in the line:

```
int position = (int)Math.Round((counter / updateTime) * 100);
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should set _timer interval to 1000 and leave _timer1 interval on 100

Answer (score 0):

A better method would be to use the `BackgroundWorker`. See [How to: Use a Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx). The `BackgroundWorker` does its job in another thread and leaves the UI responsive. It also has a mechanism to report the progress to the UI-thread. You can use it without any special multi-threading knowledge.